# Size of a FILE ADDRESS in c++

Tags: c++

How does one determine the sizeof a pos_type or offset_type such as is used in c++ stream i/o.  You can't just write sizeof(pos_type) or sizeof(basic_streambuf::pos_type) because it is defined somehow inside a template that ... well, it's pretty complex.

It would be nice to know this at compile time.

BTW, there is a type called "streamsize" that seems to fit the bill, but sizeof(streamsize) is not a valid preprocessor term.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sizeof on an instantiation of the template. `sizeof(ifstream::pos_type)`

Comment: Well, what I get is 24 if I say sizeof(streambuf::pos_type) or if I say streambuf::pos_type x; cout << sizeof(x) ....  So, pos_type is some kind of class that can convert to an integer or something, but it is PROBABLY NOT a 24-byte file-address, if I'm not mistaken.

Please forgive me.  It's been a while since I've done much c++.

Comment: If `sizeof(T)` is 24, then T is a 24 byte type. That's pretty much the definition of `sizeof` and `byte` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

`basic_streambuf` is a [template class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/). It is not fully defined until you use it. Use `sizeof` for members of template specialization, e.g. for `streambuf::pos_type`.

Comment: Well, what I get is 24 if I say sizeof(streambuf::pos_type) or if I say streambuf::pos_type x; cout << sizeof(x) ....  So, pos_type is some kind of class that can convert to an integer or something, but it is PROBABLY NOT a 24-byte file-address, if I'm not mistaken.

Please forgive me.  It's been a while since I've done much c++.